# POSTing to web service API in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios, rest

I'm writing one of my first apps for consuming a web service in Objective C, it's a Lighthouse API client. I'm able to execute all the GETs and XML parsing correctly and quickly, but I'm having extreme trouble trying to create a new ticket via POST (http://lighthouseapp.com/api).

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest. 
I tried including the parameters on the URL (i.e. POST /projects/#{project_id}/tickets.xml?title=boo).

I've tried putting the ticket XML in the request body.

```
<ticket><title>boo</title></ticket>
```

Nothing is working. (server always sends a response back saying it needs a title) I'm very new to web services - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the Lighthouse API and here's how you go about creating a new ticket.

1. Request URL is http://{yourCustomURL}.lighthouseapp.com/projects/{ProjectID}/tickets.xml where {ProjectID} is a 5 digit number - in my case **72945**.
2. Method is POST
3. Content type should be set to application/xml
4. Body should be in the format below. All fields are optional so I only included the title

`<ticket> <assigned-user-id type="integer"></assigned-user-id> <body></body> <milestone-id type="integer"></milestone-id> <state></state> <title>Testing new ticket creation</title></ticket>`

(sorry about the formatting of  the code above, SO doesn't seem to like XML formatted code somehow?

This worked for me with a new ticket created under projectID 72945 - response received was **201 Created**

If you want to make sure your POST request is working before diving into ASIHTTPRequest, download a Firefox add-on called **POSTER** from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/). This will allow you to send an authenticated post request with all the fields above. Once you get that working, it should be a piece of cake to get ASIHTTPRequest to do the same.

Comment: Agreed - but appending the data for the POST simply doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea where to stick it (did you read the question?). Is it a header? In the body? As part of the URL?

Comment: The answer is it depends on the webservice API. Just had a quick look at Lighthouse and noticed this: `All requests must send a proper Content-Type header of 'application/xml'. Otherwise, Lighthouse won't interpret your request as an API request, and you'll likely get a 500 error back.`

Comment: By the way your ticket data should go in the body.

Comment: Done, and done. Still failing :( I'll get a curl based example here shortly

Comment: Edited my answer, have a look and see if it helps.